# Unhandled Exception: Connection reset by peer flutter

Tags: flutter

I make small app that app get data from api internet. its work but some time app lose connection with internet and I get this message error:

```
E/flutter ( 3931): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Connection reset by peer
E/flutter ( 3931): #0      IOClient.send (package:http/src/io_client.dart:88:7)
E/flutter ( 3931): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 3931): #1      BaseClient._sendUnstreamed (package:http/src/base_client.dart:93:32)
E/flutter ( 3931): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 3931): #2      _withClient (package:http/http.dart:164:12)
E/flutter ( 3931): <asynchronous suspension>
```

I'm use http library latest version.
SDK flutter 3.3.0 version.

```
Future fetchMain() async {

  var response = await http.get(Uri.parse('https://************.php'));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
     final Data = json.decode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
     List<MainModel> ListData = Data.map<MainModel>(
             (json) {
           return MainModel.fromJson(json);
         }).toList();
     return ListData;

  } else {

  }
}
```

The connection remains disconnected from the Internet for about 3 minutes and then works again.

Anyone have idea about that problem and how I can solve it?

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Put a try-catch block in the fetchMain function and handle possible errors